# $\pi:M_n\to B(K)$ be a unital $*$-homomorphism. Prove, upto equivalence $K=H_1\oplus\cdots\oplus H_n$ with $H_i=H$ such that $\pi(E_{ij})$ satisfies

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, completely-positive-maps

This is an exercise (4.11) from the book [Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Completely_Bounded_Maps_and_Operator_Alg/VtSFHDABxMIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=completely%20positive%20map%20and%20operator%20algebra%20book&printsec=frontcover) by Vern Paulsen.

> Let $\pi:M_n\to\mathcal{B}(K)$ be a unital $*$-homomorphism. Prove
> that, upto equivalence, $K=H_1\oplus\cdots\oplus H_n$, with $H_i=H\
>  \forall i=1,\ldots,n$, such that $\pi(E_{i,j})$ is the identity map
> from $H_j$ to $H_i$. Show that, upto equivalence, $\pi$ is the direct
> sum of $\text{dim}(H)$ copies of the identity map.

Using this exercise, he wrote as a remark (pg no. 50) that if $\pi:M_n\to\mathcal{B}(K)$ is a $*$- homomorphism, then up to unitary equivalence, $K$ decomposes as an orthogonal direct sum on $n$-dimensional subspaces such that $\pi$ is identity representation on each of the subspace.

I'm much confused with the exercise and the above remark. As per the remark if $K=H_1\oplus\cdots\oplus\cdots\oplus H_k$ such that $\dim(H_i)=n$ and $\pi|_{H_i}$ is identity representation, then shouldn't that $\pi$ be identity representation of $M_n$?

And in the exercise, it is asked to show that $\pi$ is direct sum of $\text{dim}(H)$ copies. By the first part $K$ is direct sum of $"n"$ copies. Then is $n=\text{dim}(H)$ and $\text{dim}(K)=n^2$/ Moreover, why $K$ is finite dimensional?

Can anyone help me with any idea to understand and solve the exercise and how the remark follows from that exercise? Thanks for your help in advance.

Edit: I have understood the meaning of the remark. It says up to unitary equivalence, $K=\sum\limits_{i\in I}\oplus \mathbb{C}^n_i$ and if $P_i$ denotes the projection of $K$ onto $\Bbb{C}^n_i$, then $P_i\pi(A)|_{\Bbb{C}^n_i}=A$ for each $i\in I$.

Comment: No. $K$ need not be finite-dimensional precisely because $H$ need to be finite-dimensional. Here's an example to bear in mind: $\pi : M_2 \to B(\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\oplus \ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$ defined by $\pi(a)(\xi_1,\xi_2) := (a_{11}\xi_1+a_{12}\xi_2,a_{21}\xi_1+a_{22}\xi_2)$. Indeed, think through how the exercise and remark work out in the special case of this example.

Comment: *$H$ need not be finite-dimensional. D'oh!

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Yes, I understood. I was misinterpreting. I have understood what the remark says and the exercise implies the remark. I just need to solve the exercise. Even I think the first part of the exercise will be enough for me. Can you suggest me any hint?

Comment: maybe this helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144217/unital-representations-of-matrices-over-a-c-algebra-are-inflations-of-unital

Comment: With $(E_{jk})_{j,k=1}^n$ the usual system of matrix units in $M_n$, consider the operators $\pi(E_{jj})$.  These are orthogonal projections (why?) with mutually orthogonal ranges (why?) that sum to $K$ (why?). So that's a decomposition of $K$ into an orthogonal direct sum of subspaces. This does not yet explain how the spaces $\pi(E_{jj}) K$ are equivalent (i.e., are identifiable with the same "$H$"). As the hint suggests, this relates to the $\pi(E_{ij})$ (they implement isometries between the spaces $E_j$ and $E_i$). (It's helpful to focus on algebra, and not explicitly on basis/dimension.)